# Did William Shakespeare help make the KJV bible?

Tags: history, bible, literature, william-shakespeare, religious-texts

[Many believe because of the placement of specific words in Psalm 46 that William Shakespeare helped in the translation of the King James bible to English](http://bestfunfacts.com/bible.html).

> In 1610, the year of the final editing stages, Shakespeare would have been 46 years old (born April 1564). Psalms 46 (approximately the middle of the Bible) has a unique subliminal message, or does it?? Counting from the beginning of Psalm 46, the 46th word is shake. Counting from the end of Psalm 46, the 46th word is spear. Is it possible for these words to be a mere coincident? Or is it true that on Shakespeare’s 46th birthday, while editing the King James Version of the Bible, he chose Psalm 46, and made sure that combining the 46th word from the beginning and the 46th word from the end will read “Shake spear”?

While I am inclined to accept that this is just a bit of misplaced pattern recognition, I am interested in what the scholarly evidence actually supports.

Comment: The 46th word from the end is not "spear" but "in." The word "spear" is 47th from the end. See [biblegateway](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2046&version=KJV), or a more [original version](http://www.onlythrujesus.org/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/1611kingjamesbiblepdf.pdf), both agree.

Comment: What's more, this isn't such a fantastic coincidence, as the word "shake" appears 39 times throughout the bible, and the words "spear" or "speare" appear 44 times, most closely in one line: "he laugheth at the shaking of a speare"

Comment: Hence the skepticism.  You know how sometimes people just make stuff up to create some sort of claim, which I am betting is the true origin of this.  I doubt people expected you to actually verify it like that Flimzy!  :)

Comment: "Is it possible for these words to be a mere coincident[sic]?"  Yes.

Comment: Did the major characters all kill each other off in the end with poisons and whatnot?  Perhaps there's even a "Lost Last Supper" painting to this effect that shows everyone dead at the dinner table from food poisoning?  ;-)

Comment: For those who want to explore the text for more coincidences, there is an interactive, explorable version of the entire KJV text [here](http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/kjv_v2_3/Phrasesearch?:embed=y&:toolbar=no&:display_count=no).

Comment: I thought that story was invented by Anthony Burgess for his fictional biography of Shakespeare ... *Nothing Like the Sun* (1964)  A pretty good joke if people are taking it seriously!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**TL;DR: The claim has dubious origins and no solid proof**

I have seen this claim repeated by [numerologists](http://www.light-of-truth.com/666/KJV.html), but not by literature experts.

In fact, from a literature standpoint, it is a pretty ludicrous claim, since [we are not even sure that Shakespeare wrote the text that is actually attributed to him](http://shakespeareauthorship.com/), let alone the King James version of the Bible.

The claim in itself is not supported by any facts. So what if Shakespeare was 46 at the time? Why would he use his age to secretly sign a translation—and, by the way, why would he do the translation at all? Are the words shake and spear actually a literal transaltion of the original words? Does it mean that he was also the original *hebrew* author of the Bible?

It is well known who the authors were:

> The translators were scholarly men who were experts in the biblical languages, and they were convinced of the inerrancy and authority of Scripture.

—[source](http://www.allabouttruth.org/king-james-bible.htm)

Finally, the translation process [was tightly regulated, and the translation was peer-reviewed](http://www.av1611.org/kjv/kjvhist.html) for accuracy. This alone is a good indicator that a single author would not be able to insert terms at will in the translation.

> Fifteen general rules were advanced for the guidance of the translators:

[...]

> 8 . Every particular Man of each Company, to take the same Chapter or Chapters, and having translated or amended them severally by himself, where he thinketh good, all to meet together, confer what they have done, and agree for their Parts what shall stand.

Comment: But then the terms were already there, at approximately "right" places. All you have to do is to carefully pick phrases, so that the word-count comes out as desired. It is something that you technically can pull off, even with peer-review if your work meets the quality criteria. - Even if it were true, it would be a completely innocent joke. Too bad that the actual word-count doesn't come out right, though. And was Shakespeare known to use similar "hidden messages" in his other works?

Comment: The persons responsible have been sacked.

Answer (score 7):

It's not true, simply because the numbers are off.  We can count the words ourselves. [Psalm 46, KJV (1611)](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1611_Psalms-Chapter-46/):

> **1** [To<sup>1</sup> the<sup>2</sup> chiefe<sup>3</sup> Musician<sup>4</sup> for<sup>5</sup> the<sup>6</sup> sonnes<sup>7</sup> of<sup>8</sup> Korah<sup>9</sup>, a<sup>10</sup> song<sup>11</sup> vpon<sup>12</sup> Alamoth<sup>13</sup>.] God<sup>14</sup> is<sup>15</sup> our<sup>16</sup> refuge<sup>17</sup> and<sup>18</sup> strength<sup>19</sup>: a<sup>20</sup> very<sup>21</sup> present<sup>22</sup> helpe<sup>23</sup> in<sup>24</sup> trouble<sup>25</sup>.
>
> **2** Therfore<sup>26</sup> will<sup>27</sup> not<sup>28</sup> we<sup>29</sup> feare<sup>30</sup>, though<sup>31</sup> the<sup>32</sup> earth<sup>33</sup> be<sup>34</sup> remoued<sup>35</sup>: and<sup>36</sup> though<sup>37</sup> the<sup>38</sup> mountaines<sup>39</sup> be<sup>40</sup> caried<sup>41</sup> into<sup>42</sup> the<sup>43</sup> midst<sup>44</sup> of<sup>45</sup> the<sup>46</sup> ...

Now it might be reasonable to exclude the parenthesized text, in which case we come to:

> **1** [To the chiefe Musician for the sonnes of Korah, a song vpon Alamoth.] God<sup>1</sup> is<sup>2</sup> our<sup>3</sup> refuge<sup>4</sup> and<sup>5</sup> strength<sup>6</sup>: a<sup>7</sup> very<sup>8</sup> present<sup>9</sup> helpe<sup>10</sup> in<sup>11</sup> trouble<sup>12</sup>.
>
> **2** Therfore<sup>13</sup> will<sup>14</sup> not<sup>15</sup> we<sup>16</sup> feare<sup>17</sup>, though<sup>18</sup> the<sup>19</sup> earth<sup>20</sup> be<sup>21</sup> remoued<sup>22</sup>: and<sup>23</sup> though<sup>24</sup> the<sup>25</sup> mountaines<sup>26</sup> be<sup>27</sup> caried<sup>28</sup> into<sup>29</sup> the<sup>30</sup> midst<sup>31</sup> of<sup>32</sup> the<sup>33</sup> sea<sup>34</sup>.
>
> **3** Though<sup>35</sup> the<sup>36</sup> waters<sup>37</sup> thereof<sup>38</sup> roare<sup>39</sup>, and<sup>40</sup> be<sup>41</sup> troubled<sup>42</sup>, though<sup>43</sup> the<sup>44</sup> mountaines<sup>45</sup> shake<sup>46</sup> …

But counting from the end:

> … the speare<sup>-47</sup> in<sup>-46</sup> sunder<sup>-45</sup>, he<sup>-44</sup> burneth<sup>-43</sup> the<sup>-42</sup> chariot<sup>-41</sup> in<sup>-40</sup> the<sup>-39</sup> fire<sup>-38</sup>.
>
> **10** Be<sup>-37</sup> stil<sup>-36</sup>, and<sup>-35</sup> know<sup>-34</sup> that<sup>-33</sup> I<sup>-32</sup> am<sup>-31</sup> God<sup>-30</sup>: I<sup>-29</sup> will<sup>-28</sup> bee<sup>-27</sup> exalted<sup>-26</sup> among<sup>-25</sup> the<sup>-24</sup> heathen<sup>-23</sup>, I<sup>-22</sup> will<sup>-21</sup> be<sup>-20</sup> exalted<sup>-19</sup> in<sup>-18</sup> the<sup>-17</sup> earth<sup>-16</sup>.
>
> **11** The<sup>-15</sup> Lord<sup>-14</sup> of<sup>-13</sup> hosts<sup>-12</sup> is<sup>-11</sup> with<sup>-10</sup> vs<sup>-9</sup>; the<sup>-8</sup> God<sup>-7</sup> of<sup>-6</sup> Iacob<sup>-5</sup> is<sup>-4</sup> our<sup>-3</sup> refuge<sup>-2</sup>. Selah<sup>-1</sup>.

Now I'm no numerologist, but I'm pretty sure 47 != 46.

Of course if we discount the last word, *Selah*, then *speare* is the 46th word... but why should we skip the last word? It's still a word.

Comment: One could easily argue that `Selah` is the end (0) rather than one word before the end (-1).

Comment: @OrangeDog: Wouldn't that make "To" 0, instead of 1, as well?

Comment: Not if "To" is the first (1st) word. I mean to imply that there are stronger arguments than exploiting an ambiguity in how to count the words.

Comment: @OrangeDog: If you use a 0 index from one end, you ought to from the other, as well. So while I'm willing to accept there may be other ways to count, one ought to be consistent.  Then again, this is numerology we're talking about... I'm not sure how scientific I ought to expect a practitioner to be.

Comment: @Flimzy Given that Selah can be interpreted as a [musical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selah), it might actually be appropriate to not treat it as a word. That makes this argument weak. Sklivvz's argument is more independent of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The translation of King James was a big project that took at least 47 scholars six years to complete. The translators and revisers were organised in 6 teams, overseen by the Bishop of Canterbury (Source: [Encyclopdia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/King-James-Version)). The idea that some translator could just decide to take a psalm and put an Easter egg into it without anybody noticing is rather fanciful and seems to underestimate the importance of the project for all those involved.